# Is Apache Tomcat Blocking other thread during Eclipse debug?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat6

My debug setup is currently using tomcat (6.0) as server in my eclipse.

I am trying to test concurrency check for a long task (about 3mins). So when other session to the servlet tries to do the same process. I noticed while the first session blocks the server. The other session cannot even load other pages.

Is there a setting in tomcat or eclipse that needs to be set for this to work?

Comment: Because the other requests also have to go thru the debug point. It looks like you are trying to isolate only 1 request thread in debug & rest in non-debug mode. I don't think that's possible when you have triggered concurrent requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried editing the properties of the breakpoint so that it only pauses its own thread, or written conditions to only stop for the correct request (not that I know exactly what variables you have to work with at that point)?

Comment: actually I did not placed break point. I also checked the code and it does not used any synchronized method too. Hmmm.. Maybe because the loop is dumping a lot of console log. and the console log is synchronized? The loop basically inserts about 30000 records in succession.